# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit Laravel 8.12

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have a Laravel project that should be deployed on Linux machine and served by Nginx.

It runs on PHP 7.4

I cloned project from Git, install vendor packages, and changed .env file for application desired state.

But when I try to access website, I got an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit90740c17631bd3f3e829063649c6f6e0::getLoader()
```

There is my autoload.php content:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600) {
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    }
    $err = 'Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for autoloading on PHP <5.6 and you are running '.PHP_VERSION.', please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.'.PHP_EOL;
    if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
        if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli' || PHP_SAPI === 'phpdbg') {
            fwrite(STDERR, $err);
        } elseif (!headers_sent()) {
            echo $err;
        }
    }
    trigger_error(
        $err,
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit90740c17631bd3f3e829063649c6f6e0::getLoader();
```

I have already tried almost every solution in the internet. But none of them solved my problem.

I just wanna know that it's server-side error or application-side error?

Comment: Perhaps something failed to build your autoloader, the class name should match the content of `autoload_real.php`, this should all be auto generated. perhaps you need to re-execute your composer install.

Comment: I have already re-executed `composer install` command. Also `vendor/autoload.php` and `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php` are matching. But no error seen during the first installation. Everything was okay.

Comment: I wonder if opcache has cached the script, have you re-stated your webserver? or in the the case of PHP-FPM, the daemon?